# Stripe - Add new card to existing customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a need to add a card to a pre-existing customer. Here's what I did:

## 1. obtain token from user submission

```
card_token = request.POST('stripeToken')
```

## 2. retrieve a customer

```
customer =  stripe.Customer.retrieve('cus_xxxxxxxxxx')
```

## 3. add card to this customer

```
customer.Cards.create(card=card_token)
```

It is **# 3** that I'm having trouble because it looks like the customer doesn't have method Cards, but I've seen people done it elsewhere.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 30):

If you are on the `2015-02-18` API version or later then the `cards` attribute has been changed to `sources` as you can see in the [changelog](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2015-02-18)

The documentation on the [Create Card API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card) shows the following code now:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve('cus_xxxxxxxxxx')
customer.sources.create(card=card_token)
```

You can find your API version in the API keys [settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) in the dashboard and you can also use the `Stripe-Version` header to force your API request to an older API version so that `cards` still work as explained in the [Versioning](https://stripe.com/docs/api#versioning) documentation:

```
stripe.api_version = '2015-01-26'
```

Answer (score 6):

2019 Update: Things have changed a bit with Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) requirements in Europe; you'll now probably want to use the Setup Intents API to collect card details upfront for future payments.

This new API is both PCI and SCA compliant. You can learn more [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/saving-cards-without-payment)
 or check out this sample code on GitHub: https://github.com/stripe-samples/saving-card-without-payment.

You can also do this [entirely with Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/collecting) now as well!

Answer (score -1):

Example (customerId - cus_xxxxxxxxxx):

```
    Stripe.apiKey = stripeApiKey;

    Customer customer = Customer.retrieve(customerId);

    Map<String, Object> cardParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    cardParams.put("number", "4242424242424242");
    cardParams.put("exp_month", "12");
    cardParams.put("exp_year", "2018");
    cardParams.put("cvc", "314");

    Map<String, Object> tokenParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    tokenParams.put("card", cardParams);
    Token cardToken = Token.create(tokenParams);

    Map<String, Object> sourceParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    sourceParams.put("source", cardToken.getId()); //?
    Card source = (Card) customer.getSources().create(sourceParams);
    logger.info("Card created: " + source.toString());
```

Comment: CAUTION: It is a security best practice to never handle the card number or cvc in your server side code.  Doing so puts your server into PCI scope which is something that most developers want to avoid. Anyone using this code will have a much more challenging/expensive time with achieving PCI compliance than if they avoided server side handling of sensitive card data.